# Можно ли обойтись без массива в подсчете?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
EXP_NEED = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
async def add_exp(p, bet):
    exp = round(bet*(0.7/15000))
    p.exp += exp
    if p.exp >= EXP_NEED[p.lvl]:
        p.lvl += 1

    await db.update(p)

    return exp
```

Сейчас у меня такая костыльная система повышения уровней, можно ли обойтись без массива? C учетом что для апа каждого уровня требуется на 100 експы больше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
if p.exp >= 100*(p.lvl + 1):
    p.lvl += 1
```